# How to increase the 128byte limit of CONTEXT_INFO in SQLServer 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, context-info

It's like a context space for ants!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to increase the size of the [CONTEXT_INFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180125%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).  It is 128 bytes, and we cannot change it.

If you need more space, you could implement your own session context information.  You could create a permanent ContextInfo or global ##ContextInfo or tempdb..ContextInfo table that holds all the data you neeed to track per session.  Set the table's primary key to something unique like an [IDENTITY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).  You could also use the [@@SPID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189535%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) of the current connection.

When a request is started, INSERT a record into this ContextInfo table (or lookup the existing record on the @@SPID), and [SET CONTEXT_INFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187768%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to the associated key (or just use the @@SPID).  After your connection is finished, clean up the ContextInfo table and clear the CONTEXT_INFO information.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it more like a "cookie" than a "variable".